# Merge two workspaces

Tags: eclipse

**Given** :

- 2 workspaces `A` & `B` (well, actually more), each reference bunch of outside-of-workspace projects scattered around my file system (i.e. there is only `.metadata` inside the workspace, no project stored)

**Goal** :

- have new workspace `AB` which will group all projects of `A` plus projects of `B`.
- same project being occasionally both in `A` and `B` should appear in `AB`.
- Bonus requirement : new workspace preserves `working sets` of workspaces `A` and `B` as well (may also require some "*merging*" of `working sets`). Is it possible ?

Brute-force solution is to create list of projects for each workspace, create new workspace and import all of the projects from list manually. And may be then manually try to re-create `working sets`. 
I wonder if there is less painful solution.

Thanks a lot. Feel free to give additional suggestions on projects/workspaces/etc. organization that may make life little easier.

Comment: seriously, no one ? Is the question that stupid? Or I am trying to get too much of eclipse ? Or everyone hates me ?

Answer (score 5):

Kiruwka,

I know of no other way than to import individual projects, a brute force workaround solution found on Eclipse Forums:

To create a new AB workspace, create a directory/folder (e.g., C:\AB_Workspace), then select this workspace when launching Eclipse or switch from File > Switch Workspace.

Once you are in the new workspace, you can import projects into it:  Select: File > Import > General > Existing Projects into Workspace.  Click Next, then Browse to directory with Projects you want to import.  Works fine, but each individual project is imported individually.

Eclipse Forums has solutions: try there if no one answers you here quickly.